# unable to call functions with "onclick" with a div element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an exercise to create a reaction game to with Javascript. I need to create random squares and circles with random positions and colors. I need the ability to click on the shapes and to make it to where this random shape pops at another random location and random color. My on click event to re run the functions is not working, what am I doing wrong? It works when I refresh the page also, tried creating a separate button tag and assigned it an ID to do the on click function like that but still didn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Test 2</title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">

#box1 {
position:relative;

}

</style>



<body>

<h1>Test Your Reactions!</h1>

<p>Click on the boxes and circle as quickly as you can!</p>

<p><strong>Your time:</strong></p>

<div id = "box1"></div>

<script type = "text/javascript">


function randomColor() {
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
document.getElementById("box1").style.backgroundColor=bgColor;
console.log(bgColor);
}

function randomPosition() {

var pixel = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
var pixel2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 350);
var position = pixel+"px";
var position2 = pixel2+"px";
document.getElementById("box1").style.marginLeft = position;
document.getElementById("box1").style.marginTop = position2;
console.log(position);
console.log(position2);
}

function randomSize() {
s= Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 300) + 200);
sPixels = s + "px";
document.getElementById("box1").style.width = sPixels;
document.getElementById("box1").style.height = sPixels;
var circle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
if (circle == 1) {

document.getElementById("box1").style.borderRadius="50%";

} else {

document.getElementById("box1").style.borderRadius="none";
}
console.log(sPixels);

}
document.getElementById("box1").onclick = randomColor(); randomPosition(); randomSize();
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This row is wrong:

```
document.getElementById("box1").onclick = randomColor(); randomPosition(); randomSize();
```

You are assigning the result of the call to randomColor (which is `undefined`) to the onclick handler, not the function. And you are not calling the other functions when you click, only when the page is loaded the first time.

I suggest that you create a new function, with everything you want to do when the user click on the box:

```
function clickOnBox() {
  randomPosition();
  randomSize();
  randomColor();
}
```

And then you can bind it like this:

```
document.getElementById("box1").onclick = clickOnBox; // assign the function as click handler
clickOnBox(); // call it the first time.
```

I did some cleanup of your code, since you have a lot of repetition.

```
// Save reference to box1.
const box1 = document.getElementById("box1");

// function to get a random integer
function rndint(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

// function to get a pixel string
function pixel(value) {
  return value + 'px';
}

function randomColor() {
  const max = 256;
  box1.style.backgroundColor =
    `rgb(${rndint(max)},${rndint(max)},${rndint(max)})`;
}

function randomPosition() {
  box1.style.marginLeft = pixel( rndint(1000) );
  box1.style.marginTop = pixel( rndint(350) );
}

function randomSize() {
  box1.style.width = box1.style.height = pixel( (rndint( 100 ) + 100) );
  if ( rndint(2) ) {
    box1.style.borderRadius = "50%";
  } else {
    box1.style.borderRadius = "none";
  }
}

function clickOnBox() {
  randomPosition();
  randomSize();
  randomColor();
}

box1.onclick = clickOnBox;
clickOnBox();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help it worked and also thank you for the code organizing tip, I am still very new at this!

Comment: @Ctech21 It is obvious that you are new to this ;) That's why I thought that I should show you some suggestions for improvement. Here is some advice: When you write code and see that you write the same thing over and over again, like `Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);` or `document.getElementById("box1")`, consider if you should create a function or put the value in a variable. It is less to type, and therefore less places to makes mistakes on.

Answer (score 0):

You need change to

```
document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("click", 
 function(){randomColor(); randomPosition(); randomSize();})
```

or

```
document.getElementById("box1").onclick = 
   function(){randomColor(); randomPosition(); randomSize()};
```

Because with your code, you only assign `randomColor()` method to click event.

`randomPosition(); randomSize()` run 1 time when page load.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Test 2</title>
</head>

<style type="text/css">

#box1 {
position:relative;

}

</style>



<body>

<h1>Test Your Reactions!</h1>

<p>Click on the boxes and circle as quickly as you can!</p>

<p><strong>Your time:</strong></p>

<div id = "box1">A</div>

<script type = "text/javascript">


function randomColor() {
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
var z = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
var bgColor = "rgb(" + x + "," + y + "," + z + ")";
document.getElementById("box1").style.backgroundColor=bgColor;
console.log(bgColor);
}

function randomPosition() {

var pixel = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
var pixel2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 350);
var position = pixel+"px";
var position2 = pixel2+"px";
document.getElementById("box1").style.marginLeft = position;
document.getElementById("box1").style.marginTop = position2;
console.log(position);
console.log(position2);
}

function randomSize() {
s= Math.floor(Math.random() * (200 - 300) + 200);
sPixels = s + "px";
document.getElementById("box1").style.width = sPixels;
document.getElementById("box1").style.height = sPixels;
var circle = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
if (circle == 1) {

document.getElementById("box1").style.borderRadius="50%";

} else {

document.getElementById("box1").style.borderRadius="none";
}
console.log(sPixels);

}

document.getElementById("box1").onclick = function(){randomColor(); randomPosition(); randomSize()};
//document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener("click", function(){randomColor(); randomPosition(); randomSize();})
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, still very new to coding and Javascript and it is much appreciated.